# How to make a notification from broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

So i've been struggling with proximity alerts and finally my code works, but i don't know how to make it show me a notification instead of a log message:

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "in receiver");

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    if (entering) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering receiverrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
    } else {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
    }

  }
}
```

Well i tryed to implement this but it won't work cause i can get no context from proximityIntentReceiver class

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new    Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationView.class);

    /** Adding content to the notificationIntent, which will be displayed on
     * viewing the notification
     */
    notificationIntent.putExtra("content", notificationContent );

    /** This is needed to make this intent different from its previous intents */
    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:/"+ (int)System.currentTimeMillis()));

    /** Creating different tasks for each notification. See the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK */
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    /** Getting the System service NotificationManager */
    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    /** Configuring notification builder to create a notification */
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentText(notificationContent)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_notification)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(tickerMessage)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

    /** Creating a notification from the notification builder */
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

    /** Sending the notification to system.
     * The first argument ensures that each notification is having a unique id
     * If two notifications share same notification id, then the last notification replaces the first notification
     * */
    nManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
```

also `NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);` won't work cause i guess it's deprecated.
How can i show a notification from this class? thanks

Comment: if the Context in onReceve method is not working then why not initialize it with the Application Context in the constructor ? Also make sure that onReceive is actually being reached.

Comment: Instead of `getApplicationContext` you can try using the `context` object passed to the `onReceive` method.

Comment: thanks, works. I can't upvote you cause i have no rep, sorry

Comment: Will post it as answer for others' benefit as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your BroadcastReceiver, use the `context` object passed to the onReceive method instead of `getApplicationContext`. That should give the notification proper context to run on.